# Deployment error (Cert chain error)

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst

During our deployment using ant script or through MFP console, we run to this error (It also appear on the console) :

We are unable to resolve it, any suggestion.

Server version 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103

```
deploy:
  [sshexec] cmd : (cd /apps/release/project/Ant_Files/MobileFirstConsole;  ./buildAdapters.sh)
  [sshexec] JAVA_HOME=/was85/AppServer/java_1.7.1_64/
  [sshexec] Buildfile: /apps/release/MobileBanking/Ant_Files/MobileFirstConsole/wl_adapter_install-MB.xml
  [sshexec]      [echo] /apps/release/MobileBanking/Hybrid_Binary_Files/MBCABMLocatorAdapter.adapter ...
  [sshexec] 
  [sshexec] install-adapter:
  [sshexec]     [wladm] Error accessing https://domin:port/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/MobileBanking/adapters?locale=en_US: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
  [sshexec]     [wladm] FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.
  [sshexec]     [wladm] FWLSE3012E: JMX connection error. Reason: "FWLSE3012E: JMX connection error. Reason: "[SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=was.dmgr.company.com, OU=Root Certificate, OU=cell_was, OU=dmgr, O=IBM, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorExcept
  [sshexec] ion: The certificate issued by CN=was.dmgr.company.com, OU=Root Certificate, OU=cell_was, OU=dmgr, O=IBM, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error]". Check the application server logs for details.". Check the application server logs for details.
  [sshexec] 
  [sshexec] BUILD FAILED
  [sshexec] /apps/release/MobileBanking/Ant_Files/MobileFirstConsole/wl_adapter_install-MB.xml:27: com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTException: Error accessing https://domin:port/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/MobileBanking/adapters?locale=en_US: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
  [sshexec] FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.
  [sshexec] FWLSE3012E: JMX connection error. Reason: "FWLSE3012E: JMX connection error. Reason: "[SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=was.dmgr.company.com, OU=Root Certificate, OU=cell_was, OU=dmgr, O=IBM, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The cer
  [sshexec] tificate issued by CN=was.dmgr.company.com, OU=Root Certificate, OU=cell_was, OU=dmgr, O=IBM, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error]". Check the application server logs for details.". Check the application server logs for details.
  [sshexec]     at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getResponse(RESTClient.java:1282)
  [sshexec]     at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getResponseWithTimeout(RESTClient.java:1359)
  [sshexec]     at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getPOSTResponse(RESTClient.java:1477)
  [sshexec]     at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getPOSTFileResponse(RESTClient.java:1499)
  [sshexec]     at com.ibm.worklight.admin.commands.DeployAdapter.getResponse(DeployAdapter.java:41)
  [sshexec]     at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.ActionClient.execute(ActionClient.java:93)
  [sshexec]     at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.types.AbstractActionElement.executeCommand(AbstractActionElement.java:77)
  [sshexec]     at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.types.ActionElement.executeCommands(ActionElement.java:43)
  [sshexec]     at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.WladmTask.executeCommands(WladmTask.java:734)
  [sshexec]     at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.WladmTask.execute(WladmTask.java:473)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
  [sshexec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [sshexec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
  [sshexec]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
  [sshexec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
  [sshexec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
  [sshexec] 
  [sshexec] Total time: 4 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the log:

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=was.dmgr.company.com, OU=Root Certificate, OU=cell_was, OU=dmgr, O=IBM, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.;

Whatever this certificate it, it may have been wrongly generated. I suggest to double-check the information that was provided to create it and re-generate it. Then, try again.